# Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached

Tags: matlab, recursion, limit, max

I have received the following message when I tried to run (`adpcm_encoder`).

```
??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in ==> fileparts
```

I have searched for this problem at many sites but I didn't find a specific solution.

the code is:

```
function adpcm_y = adpcm_encoder(raw_y)



Y = wavread('two.wav');
Y_en = adpcm_encoder(Y);


IndexTable = [-1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 4, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 4, 6, 8];

StepSizeTable = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 41, 45, 50, 55, 60, 66, 73, 80, 88, 97, 107, 118, 130, 143, 157, 173, 190, 209, 230, 253, 279, 307, 337, 371, 408, 449, 494, 544, 598, 658, 724, 796, 876, 963, 1060, 1166, 1282, 1411, 1552, 1707, 1878, 2066, 2272, 2499, 2749, 3024, 3327, 3660, 4026, 4428, 4871, 5358, 5894, 6484, 7132, 7845, 8630, 9493, 10442, 11487, 12635, 13899, 15289, 16818, 18500, 20350, 22385, 24623, 27086, 29794, 32767];

prevsample = 0;
previndex = 1;

Ns = length(raw_y);
n = 1;

raw_y = 32767 * raw_y;          % 16-bit operation

while (n <= Ns)
predsample = prevsample;
index = previndex;
step = StepSizeTable(index);

diff = raw_y(n) - predsample;
if (diff >= 0)
    code = 0;
else
    code = 8;
    diff = -diff;
end

tempstep = step;
if (diff >= tempstep)
    code = bitor(code, 4);
    diff = diff - tempstep;
end
tempstep = bitshift(tempstep, -1);
if (diff >= tempstep)
    code = bitor(code, 2);
    diff = diff - tempstep;
end
tempstep = bitshift(tempstep, -1);
if (diff >= tempstep)
    code = bitor(code, 1);
end

diffq = bitshift(step, -3);
if (bitand(code, 4))
    diffq = diffq + step;
end
if (bitand(code, 2))
    diffq = diffq + bitshift(step, -1);
end
if (bitand(code, 1))
    diffq = diffq + bitshift(step, -2);
end

if (bitand(code, 8))
    predsample = predsample - diffq;
else
    predsample = predsample + diffq;
end

if (predsample > 32767)
    predsample = 32767;
elseif (predsample < -32768)
    predsample = -32768;
end

index = index + IndexTable(code+1);

if (index < 1)
    index = 1;
end
if (index > 89)
    index = 89;
end

prevsample = predsample;
previndex = index;

adpcm_y(n) = bitand(code, 15);
%adpcm_y(n) = code;
n = n + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because you have a function that calls itself recursively with no stopping condition. It is the recursive equivalent of an infinite loop.

The issue is the second line of the function:

```
function adpcm_y = adpcm_encoder(raw_y)

    Y = wavread('two.wav');
    Y_en = adpcm_encoder(Y);
```

The second line of the function recursively calls the function again, but since there is no stopping condition, it continues until you hit the maximum recursion limit error.

Comment: How can I hit the maximum recursion limit error??
What should I do?

Comment: @user1103780 In general, two ways come to mind: you could have a correct function that is dealing with a huge problem recursively or you could have an incorrect function that always hits the recursion limit. Your function is in the latter category because it does not ever run anything except its first two lines. It does not matter what you set the recursion limit to because `adpcm_y` does infinite recursion. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the recursive call in `adpcm_y`, but what it does now is not likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this for very simple code, write the script as a function instead, that helped me for some reason.

For example, instead of:

```
clc
clear all
syms s
sys = s^2 + 2*s
solve(s)
```

do:

```
function L8
clc
clear all
syms s
sys = s^2 + 2*s
solve(s)
end
```

Comment: Unless you called your script file `solve` or `clc` or `syms` or any of the other function names used inside the script, I don't see how you could possibly get a recursion there. Still, putting your code in a function is always good. There is no need to call `clear` at the top of the function, which is one of the reasons it's better to write functions than scripts -- a function always starts with an empty workspace (except for any input arguments).

Comment: Note also that `clear` by itself is sufficient to clear the workspace. `clear all` also clears loaded functions from memory, which slows down your code and is generally not useful.